# Pusher in android studio

Tags: android-studio, pusher

Push notifications.

I have a web system (.NET MVC) for the company where he works, in which the user does some CRUD operations. So I made an application in Android Studio which shows a recycling list all the records that users create in the web system that it mentions at the beginning, for this it creates a .NET MVC server as well. But what I need is that every time I click Insert (to the database) in the web system, I get a notification to the mobile app.

I was reading about PUSHER, I signed up and gave me the following code, and I don't know what to do with this code, how it works.

Client Android

```java
PusherOptions options = new PusherOptions();
        options.setCluster("xxx");
        Pusher pusher = new Pusher("xxx", options);

        pusher.connect(new ConnectionEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConnectionStateChange(ConnectionStateChange change) {
                System.out.println("Estado cambio de " + change.getPreviousState() + " a " + change.getCurrentState());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String message, String code, Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error de conexión! " +
                        "\ncode: " + code +
                        "\nmessage: " + message +
                        "\nException: " + e
                );
            }
        }, ConnectionState.ALL);

        Channel channel = pusher.subscribe("my-channel");

        channel.bind("my-event", new SubscriptionEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(PusherEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Received event with data: " + event.toString());
            }
        });
```

Server MVC

```html
 public class HelloWorldController : Controller
     {
            [HttpPost]
            public async Task<ActionResult> Notificaciones()
            {
                var options = new PusherOptions
                {
                    Cluster = "xxx",
                    Encrypted = true
                };

                var pusher = new Pusher(
                  "xxx",
                  "xxxx",
                  "xxxx",
                  options);

                var result = await pusher.TriggerAsync(
                  "my-channel",
                  "my-event",
                  new { message = "hello world" });

            return new HttpStatusCodeResult((int)HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
        }
```

The truth is that I am very lost and how to use it, I must use the databases that they have on a private server of my company. If someone can guide me or tell me about some other way to do what I need. Thank you

Comment: I don't see .Net support in their Server SDKs list (https://pusher.com/docs/beams/reference/all-libraries) , could you show us more from your server-side script?